# Text on Hover an image in Css

Tags: css, text, jquery-plugins, hover

Hey guys I'm trying to implement Paper unfoding effect in a webpage of a wesite I'm developing. Im using the pfold jquery plugin, but I want a text to appear on hover and I did it many times but doesnt work. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="uc-container">
   <div class="uc-initial-content">
<!--<img src="fm.png" alt="FM" /> -->

<img src="fm.png" alt="Fm" title="Fm" id="hoverFm">
<p class="textSponsor">92.7 BIG FM</p>

<span class="icon-eye"></span>
</div>
<div class="uc-final-content">
<img src="fm.png" alt="FM" /> 

    <div class="title"><h4>FM</h4> <a href="http://drbl.in/dMLS" class="icon-link"></a></div>
<span class="icon-cancel"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

And This is the CSS For same:

```
#hoverFm .textSponsor{
position: relative;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
visibility: hidden;
}

#hoverFm:hover .textSponsor{
visibility: visible;
}
```

When Im doing this the text just simply comes below my picture . I'm not getting where I'm going wrong. And when I'm creating a new div which contains only `<img>` and `<p>` tag then my image is getting small (I guess its because of the code I wrote for resizing and paper folding effect which is gettin hampered due to this and then also text on hover is not coming)

If you guys wanna see what actually I'm making :

The link to the demo site is: http://tympanus.net/Development/PFold/index3.html

and the code for same is available at link: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/17/pfold-paper-like-unfolding-effect/comment-page-2/#comment-450779

And the github link for code is: https://github.com/codrops/PFold

I tried it a lot to figure out but was unable so please help someone. It will really be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I've tried adding a text on hover on the demo page and it looked ok, could you provide a fiddle or anything to demostrate your problem?

Comment: Oh, yeah, it's in the selector, now I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#hoverFm:hover .textSponsor
```

This does never really happen, because `.textSponsor` is not a **child** of `#hoverGM`, it is a **sibling**. You need to use the next selector, which is `+`:

```
#hoverFm:hover + .textSponsor
```

You could also change the structure to

```
<div class="uc-initial-content" id="hoverFm">
    <img src="fm.png" alt="Fm" title="Fm">
    <p class="textSponsor">92.7 BIG FM</p>
```

Then your original selector would work because now it really is a child.

Comment: Ok thanks ! it solve most of it . I did the second way you told but I want the text to appear in a box kind of thing but just now its coming below the picture can you please help with this??

Comment: If you need the hover only on the image, you gonna have to use the first method or JavaScript. Or some weird positiong of elements.

Comment: I tried the first method but it doesnt work as in neither the text comes below the image nor on hover so where am I going wrong?? and I also added "+" to "#hoverFm .textSponsor"??

Comment: could you make a fiddle that I could look at please?

Comment: This is the link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/erebus/Kh6q7/5/  I actually want it to be a Box(like its coming in fiddle written "Fm" but it doesnt come in actual code . I think tht's because of the "alt" attribute of img tag) can you please help??

Comment: Well, this kinda looks like it should, maybe continue in chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38295/discussion-between-user2696258-and-jakub-michalek)